# creating football news using PHP/mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Please before all the downvotes read this as I really need an answer to this and this a genuine question.

I am trying to create a website that will show all the Football/soccer News on the site.

I was just wondering if there is an automated way of doing this so all the news get published on my site? for example there is a site thats called football.co.uk that will show all the football news live and i was wondering how they can do that? i.e. show the news and the images etc?

I will be creating the website using PHP and mysql.

I know i can use RSS feed from sites like BBC and skye but i don't think i can get the images and also RSS feed can only show the title of the news on my site. i need to show the title and when someone clicks on the title, they will be pointed to the news page on my own website!

i do apologize if this question is a bit vague but i have no other way of asking this.

so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You'll get the downvotes because you've not actually tried anything yet - we help people fix code problems, not provide free code solutions

Comment: You will have to pay for the data and it is not cheap. http://www.stats.com/data_delivery.asp. I looked into something similar a couple of years ago and I ran across this site, which provides data for some very large sites.

Comment: @MarkBaker, that is your problem. because again you did not read the question and just went for the downvote. if you read the question properly, i did NOT ask for a free code. i asked for information.

Comment: I did read the question, and I didn't actually downvote - but your question is outside the scope of SO. Try Programmers instead if you want to avoid the downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're actually asking is 2 separate questions:

1) Grabbing latest news and results text for your website

To automate news and results text for your website, you'll need to find an RSS or XML provider such as http://www.scorespro.com/livescore-xml/

2) Grabbing images to match the teams and scorers etc to make the content more engaging.

For this you will probably need to find a stock photo provider.  To automate the appearance of images you can do a keyword lookup. For example, when "Paulo Di Canio" is returned in the XML, poll your database to pick an existing image of Paulo Di Canio that you have and show that alongside the news or text.

On a slight side note, if you're thinking about using PHP and MySQL, you should give wordpress some serious consideration.  It has a bunch of plugins.  One that might be useful for you is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/soccer-info/

Hope this helps!

Comment: absolutely amazing. That is what I am looking for. Thanks ever so much.